# flutter positioning dialog to screen center

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dialog and it is called inside initState to build this before screen builds

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    popupManager();
    super.initState();
```

and this is the method which calls popupDialog

```
popupManager() async {
    String? show = await PopupManager.checkShowPopup();
    if (show == 'true') {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return PopupDialog(),
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

and  this is the Dialog Widget

```
class PopupDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const PopupDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: _buildDialogContent(context),
    );
  }
```

I have wrapped them whit `Align(alignment: Alignment.center)` or `Center` all didn't work
the one only worked was

wrapping Dialog with column and setting position

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Dialog(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: _buildDialogContent(context),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

this works... but i don't think it is the right ways to make the dialog center
is there any one knows better ways to position dialog to center of screeen

Comment: There should be an issue on current snippet on showing dialog. Can you include an image you are trying to get

Answer (score 0):

Use `alignment: Alignment.center` on `Dialog`.

```dart
class PopupDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  const PopupDialog({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      child: Text(
        "test dialog ",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And dialog can be called after 1st frame is build.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      popupManager();
    });
  }

  popupManager() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return PopupDialog();
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: sorry but i have tried to wrap with align and it didn't work at all

Comment: Did you include ` alignment: Alignment.center,` on `Dialog` as I did?

Comment: yes and didn't work...

Comment: Can you include a UI you are trying to get